# Pay plugin showing success for failed apple pay transaction in flutter app on apple pay sheet

Tags: ios, flutter, applepay

I have successfully implemented apple pay using the `pay` plugin in my e-commerce flutter app and it works just fine. The only problem is that the apple pay sheet, upon the completion of transaction, shows done (success) for both failed and successful transactions. I am showing an alert dialog when failure occurs, but still this issue is misleading and unfriendly to the users. I have tested this with Sandbox and real apple wallets and the result is same. There's no issue in my backend either as I have tested a transaction without invoking my backend endpiont and the result is no different. I am using `final res = await _payClient.showPaymentSelector(PayProvider.apple_pay, _paymentItems);` to get the token and send this to backend. It seems that my Apple Pay configuration files are also without issues; if there had been any problems, transactions wouldn't have been completed in the first place. My `pay` plugin version is `1.1.2` and my dart sdk is `>=3.0.3 <4.0.0`. I have provided the screenshot for a failed transaction below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is recognized by the team behind pay plugin
They have an official Github repo where we can post issues in the plugin:
https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/issues

If you look at the closed issue [#248](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/issues/248), you will see that they have fixed this issue and are waiting for the fix to be merged so they can put it into the new release
[Comment by pay developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k5AR.png)

Comment: Oh that is a good news. I opened that 248 issue on github a week ago. When are they going to release the next version of the pay plugin?

Comment: They just released Pay:2.0.0 and this issue is still there. Very sloppy